# curl custom slack notifications from jenkins

Tags: json, webhooks, slack

I am trying to send an custom slack notification to my slack channel using curl. Below my payload . Using curl to post notifications to Slack channel so that Team members could be able to see the Verison, s3 link and Directly they can access directly. Any suggestions or inputs  would be greatly appreciated.

```
version=1.2.4
bundleversion=1.3.4.5
SLACK_MSG="Version=$version bundleversion=$bundleversion s3link:Random "

 curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST --data-urlencode -d 
"payload='{
"username": "Kalyan",
"attachments": [
    {
        "color": "danger",
        "fields": [
            {
                "title": "Danger Event",
                "text": "$SLACK_MSG",
                "short": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "warning",
        "fields": [
            {
                "title": "Warning Event",
                "value": "This is a warning",
                "short": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "good",
        "fields": [
            {
                "title": "Good Event",
                "value": "This is good",
                "short": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
}'" https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX 

 Below Jenkins Error 

 curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 51
 curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL    
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: bundleversion=1.3.4.5
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'R'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 52
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: is
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: a
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: is
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 56
```

Any inputs Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: I think your `attachments` section is wrong. Please take a look at your `"` and `'` chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `danger` attachment has a `field` with an invalid property called `text` specified - change this property to `value` to make it into a valid Slack `field`.

You can troubleshoot Slack message payloads via the Slack Message Formatting page to see if they are valid: [here's the corrected message payload](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22username%22%3A%22Kalyan%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22color%22%3A%22danger%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22Danger%20Event%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%24SLACK_MSG%22%2C%22short%22%3Afalse%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22warning%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22Warning%20Event%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22This%20is%20a%20warning%22%2C%22short%22%3Afalse%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22good%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22Good%20Event%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22This%20is%20good%22%2C%22short%22%3Afalse%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have changed the text value to value and made corrects to syntax. But I am not able to retrieve the value in the SLACK_MSG variable  and post it on slack channel. it is just printing "SLACK_MSG".

Comment: You may need to perform some kind of variable substitution inside Jenkins to make that work correctly.

Comment: SLACK_MSG variable contains Values. can you give more little more explanation. Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this: payload and curl for custom slack notification.
I used that in Gitlab-CI.yml file for sending Job artifacts and reports to Slack. It works fine. 
The code below you can modify because I wrote that like it appears Green/Red when job Pass or Fail.

```
- 'curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data "{
    \"attachments\": [
        {
            \"mrkdwn_in\": [\"text\"],
            \"color\": \"#36a64f\",
            \"author_name\": \"<https://$Gitlab_Home_URL/${GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}|${GITLAB_USER_NAME}>($GITLAB_USER_LOGIN)\",
            \"text\": \"*Job <https://$REPO_URL/-/jobs/${CI_JOB_ID}|TESTING> was SUCCESSFUL in pipeline <https://$REPO_URL/pipelines/${CI_PIPELINE_ID}|${CI_PIPELINE_ID}>*\",
            \"fields\": [
                {
                    \"title\": \"Trigger source\",
                    \"value\": \"$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE\",
                     \"short\": true
                },
                {
                    \"title\": \"Branch\",
                    \"value\": \"<https://$REPO_URL/tree/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME|$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME>\",
                    \"short\": true
                },
                {
                    \"title\": \"Commit message\",
                    \"value\": \"<https://$REPO_URL/commit/${CI_COMMIT_SHA}|$CI_COMMIT_TITLE>\",
                    \"short\": true
                }
            ],
            \"footer\": \"<https://$REPO_URL|$CI_PROJECT_NAME>\",
            \"footer_icon\": \"https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/5847f997cef1014c0b5e48c1.png\",
        }
    ]
}" YOUR_SLACK_WEBHOOK'
```

Answer (score 0):

I will also make it simple:
Please note: There should not be any space after "content-type:" and "application/json" people do that mistake. 
and take care about backslash. You can also try this on terminal/cmd. I should work

> curl -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" --data '{\"text\":\"here_is_your_message\"}' YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL